# Failed to initialize XMSFactoryFactory

Tags: ibm-mq

I am new to IBM WebSphere MQ. I am trying to connect to MQ using IBM.XMS dll in a plugin for Dynamics CRM and getting below error.

Exception:Fatal error. Failed to initialize XMSFactoryFactory
Stack Trace: at IBM.XMS.XMSFactoryFactory.GetXmsFactory(Int32 connectionType)
at IBM.XMS.XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(Int32 connectionType)
at Mta.ACBPS.Mta.Crm.Plugins.PostMtaMessageCreate.GetConnection(IOrganizationService service, mta_mqconnection mqConnectionRecord, ITracingService tracer)
Inner Exception:System.InvalidCastException: **Unable to cast object of type 'IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsFactoryFactoryImpl' to type 'IBM.XMS.XMSFactoryFactory'.**

The source code is

```
var connectionfactory = (IConnectionFactory)null;
try
{
var factoryfactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
connectionfactory = factoryfactory.CreateConnectionFactory();
connectionfactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, mqConnectionRecord.mta_name);
connectionfactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, mqConnectionRecord.mta_HostIP);
connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, int.Parse(mqConnectionRecord.mta_Port));
connectionfactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, mqConnectionRecord.mta_Channel);
connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_V2);
connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED);

}
```

Comment: i removed the 'dynamics-crm' tag since this is clearly not relevant (maybe a typo while tagging?)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious question is: have you installed MQ client or just copied  IBM.XMS.DLL assembly from somewhere and using it? IBM.XMS has dependency on many other assemblies. Just having IBM.XMS assembly alone does not help.

IBM XMS .NET client comes bundled with MQ client. So you must install MQ client. You can download latest MQ client from [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037500).

Once you install MQ client, refer the samples in \Tools\dotnet\samples\cs\xms directory.

**Update based on comment**
I am wondering if you need to reference other XMS assemblies in your plugin so that CRM finds those dependent assemblies. As a starting point, you can reference `IBM.XMS.Client.Impl` and `IBM.XMS.Impl` and see if it helps.

Comment: I have installed MQ Client. I referenced IBM.XMS dll in my console app for C# and code is working fine. When I am using the same in my plugin for dynamics CRM then it is showing this error.

Comment: is it possible to do listen method without installing client?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed. I was referencing IBM.XMS and using ILMerge to merge assembly with my plugin code dll. I rmeoved IMLerge and now plugin is using assemblies installed in GAC for IBM.XMS.